# SIESTA basis set optimization (Enthalpy vs total energy)

Tags: siesta, basis-sets, optimization

Using SIESTA for bulk Si (not optimized, downloaded from materialsproject.org), I am trying to optimize the DZP basis set using the `PAO.EnergyShift` parameter. SIESTA official documentation mentions that one should minimize the "BASIS_ENTHALPY" instead of the total energy when performing basis optimization. The following is a plot of both the "Total Energy" and the "Basis Enthalpy" as a function of `EnergyShift`. The pseudopotential is obtained from "pseudodojo.com" (Norm conserving, scalar relativistic).

[image: Basis Enthalpy and total Energy vs EnergyShift]

The difference in energy shift that minimizes both the enthalpy and the total energy is large. The same behavior appeared also for Si slabs. So what should be considered as a good energy shift?